# Can't seem to get the TableModelListener to work

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener, tablemodel

I am creating an UI class in which everything will run (a different class will work as the runner). In this class I have a table and the table is supposed to create TableModeEvents when changed, but it doesn't seem to do so.

The console is supposed to print out "test" whenever I do anything to the table, but it is not. I've made other SSCCE and they work fine as long as I keep everything in one program (in the main method and with only subclasses and anonymous classes) but I can't seem to get it to work across classes.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
package SSCCE;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelEvent;
import javax.swing.event.TableModelListener;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class SSCCE {

static Object[][] data = { {"Abyss", Boolean.FALSE},{"Scepter", Boolean.FALSE},{"FoN", Boolean.FALSE} };
public static void main(String[] args){

    //table model------------------------------------------
    TableModel model = new AbstractTableModel(){
        Object[][] rowData = { {"Abyss", Boolean.FALSE},{"Scepter", Boolean.FALSE},{"FoN", Boolean.FALSE} };
        String[] columnNames = {"Name","Boolean"};

        public int getColumnCount() {return columnNames.length;}

          public String getColumnName(int column) {return columnNames[column];}

          public int getRowCount() {return rowData.length;}

          public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {return rowData[row][column];}

          public Class getColumnClass(int column) {return (getValueAt(0, column).getClass());}

          public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {rowData[row][column] = value;}

          public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {return (true);}
    };


    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    //tableChanged------------------------------------------
    model.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener(){
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }

    });

    //frame stuff, ignore-----------------------------------
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(table,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(500,400);
    frame.setLocation(400,200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: I don't think that there's any way to tell what you're doing wrong based on the code and text you've posted so far. Consider creating and posting an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) that shows your problem and sure that uses more than one class (but put them in one file) and you'll likely have better results here.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels +1 for pointing out that one source file can contain more than one class.  To quote from the ['Correct' section](http://pscode.org/sscce.html#co) of the SSCCE document.  *"If the language specifies only a single public class per source code file, demote all the other classes to default. This allows the example to be compiled without being split into separate files."*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you change the value of any of the table cells, the `setValueAt` method is being called, but there's no event being fired.

Try adding the `fireTableCellUpdated(row, column)` method call to your `setValueAt` method, like so:

```
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
    rowData[row][column] = value;
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
}
```

Note that you could also `fireTableDataChanged()`, but that will fire the most general event, and it's advised that you fire the most specific as it avoids unnecessary work and is capable of maintaining the selection state.

- [`fireTableCellUpdated(int row, int column)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableCellUpdated%28int,%20int%29)
- [`fireTableDataChanged()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged%28%29)

Comment: This hold listener thing is confusing to me. I thought everything was done internally, seems not. And now to learn DnD.

Comment: correct advice, but wrong event: fireTableCellUpdated instead. General rule is to always fire the most limited event type to keep the reaction as small as possible (dataChanged clears selection, f.i.)

Comment: @Nacht everything (nearly) that _could_ be done independently of the concrete implementation is indeed done :-)

Comment: -1 for sticking to dataChanged - even as a side-note, it's not a viable option

Comment: @kleopatra: Really? Wow. I disagree - it's worth mentioning so the OP doesn't see it and say "I'll just use this instead, it's easier" without knowing the differences between the two methods.

Comment: disagreeing with facts is not option as well ;-)

Comment: I actually figured it out that it was fireTableCellUpdate. Turns out, datachanged made some unwanted effects. But after I understood fire events, I just looked it up. Still, thanks for everything!

Comment: This answer needs to be linked to so many JTable questions where this method is never mentioned in any answers, 6 years later, thank you.